# SQL Server, pivot unspecified number of columns and row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I am querying number of entrance for each door per day.

To start, I query number of people enter the relevant door which is identified by "door_code column" and pass key id identified by pass_id column. So I grouped "pass_id" column to remove duplicate people in entrance.

```
SELECT 
    t1.[entrance_date],
    [door_code],
    COUNT([pass_id]) AS [entrance_count]
FROM
    (SELECT
         CONVERT(date, substring(entrance_date, 0, 9)) as [entrance_date],   
         [pass_id], [door_code]
     FROM
         dbo.entrance_history
     WHERE
         door_code IN ('000A', '000B', '000C'....continued)
     GROUP BY
         CONVERT(date, substring(entrance_date, 0, 9)), [pass_id], [door_code]) t1
WHERE
    t1.entrance_date BETWEEN '2018-03-10' AND '2018-03-13' 
GROUP BY 
    [door_code], [entrance_date]
ORDER BY 
    [door_code] DESC, [entrance_date] DESC
```

This query returns a result set like this:

```
entrance_date|door_code|entrance_count
2018-03-13   |000C     |9
2018-03-12   |000C     |23
2018-03-11   |000C     |18
2018-03-10   |000C     |19
2018-03-13   |000B     |1
2018-03-12   |000B     |1
2018-03-11   |000B     |1
2018-03-10   |000B     |1
2018-03-12   |000A     |1
.....continued
```

And I want to transform it like

```
entrance_date|000C|000B|000A
2018-03-13   |9   |1   |0
2018-03-12   |23  |1   |1
2018-03-11   |18  |1   |1
2018-03-10   |19  |1   |1
```

I tried pivot like below, but it doesn't work. 
I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
declare @doorCode nvarchar(Max) = '''000A'',''000B'',''000C'''
declare @sql nvarchar(Max);

set @sql = 'select base_table.[enterance_date], '
+ @doorCode +
' from
(SELECT t1.[entrance_date],
[door_code],
count([pass_id]) as [entrance_count]
FROM
(
    select CONVERT(date,substring(entrance_date,0,9)) as [entrance_date], [pass_id], [door_code]
    from dbo.entrance_history
    where door_code in ('+@doorCode+')
    group by CONVERT(date,substring(entrance_date,0,9)),[pass_id], [door_code]
) t1
group by [door_code], [entrance_date]
) as [base_table]
    pivot 
    (
      base_table.enterance_count 
      for base_table.[door_code] in ('+@doorCode+')
    ) as pivottable'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uzi's answer is partially correct. While it is enough to use one grouping, pass id must be included in grouping clause, so we could remove the duplicate people's entrance record. I was trying to query **number of people** entered the door,  not number of entrance.

So to do so, i first query the number of entrance per each **pass_id** like below data set.

```
entrance_date|door_code|entrance_count|pass_id
2018-03-13   |000C     |4             |P0001
2018-03-13   |000C     |2             |P0002
2018-03-13   |000C     |1             |P0003
2018-03-13   |000C     |1             |P0004
2018-03-13   |000B     |1             |P0001
2018-03-13   |000B     |1             |P0002
2018-03-13   |000B     |1             |P0003
2018-03-13   |000B     |1             |P0004
2018-03-13   |000A     |1             |P0001
.... continued
```

The result above is returned by below query.

```
select 
  CONVERT(date,substring(entrance_date,0,9)) as [entrance_date],  [door_code], count([pass_id]) as [entrance_count], [pass_id]
  from dbo.entrance_history
  where door_code in ('000A', '000B', '000C'....continued)
  group by CONVERT(date,substring(entrance_date,0,9)), [door_code], [pass_id]
```

Now i need to pivot above table to get a dataset i want. To get number of people(which is identified by "pass_id" column, according to 1 pass per 1 person rule), i need to **count** the pass_id. Then i get this query.

```
declare @doorCode nvarchar(Max) = '''000A'',''000B'',''000C'''
declare @doorCode2 nvarchar(Max) = '[000A],[000B],[000C]'
declare @sql nvarchar(Max);

set @sql = '
  select entrance_date, ' + @doorCode2 + '
  from (
    select 
      CONVERT(date,substring(entrance_date,0,9)) as [entrance_date],  [door_code], [pass_id]
      from dbo.entrance_history
      where door_code in ('+ @doorCode +')
      group by CONVERT(date,substring(entrance_date,0,9)), [door_code], [pass_id]
  ) as [base_table]
  pivot (
    count([pass_id]) 
    for [door_code] in ('+ @doorCode2 +')
  ) as [pvt] 
  order by entrance_date desc
'
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

And that returns the dataset i wanted.

```
entrance_date|000A|000B|000C
2018-03-13   |9   |4   |1
2018-03-12   |23  |1   |1
2018-03-11   |18  |1   |1
2018-03-10   |19  |1   |1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this query. I believe one grouping is enough

```
declare @doorCode nvarchar(Max) = '''000A'',''000B'',''000C'''
declare @doorCode2 nvarchar(Max) = '[000A],[000B],[000C]'
declare @sql nvarchar(Max);

set @sql = '
    select
        entrance_date, ' + @doorCode2 + '
    from (
        select 
            CONVERT(date,substring(entrance_date,0,9)) as [entrance_date], count([pass_id]) as [entrance_count], [door_code]
        from 
            dbo.entrance_history
        where 
            door_code in (' + @doorCode + ')
            group by CONVERT(date,substring(entrance_date,0,9)), [door_code]
    ) as [base_table]
    pivot (
        max([entrance_count]) for [door_code] in (' + @doorCode2 + ')
    ) as pvt
    '
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: uzi, i guess rather than using max, we need to move count function to pivot part. I posted an answer with that change. And just want to know, If using such code is injection-safe. Because i am planning on using it as stored procedure, and getting parameter for '@doorCode' and '@doorCode2'

Comment: @ringord, your posted query in the answer is not correct, and should return error. Since `pass_id` is not in group by nor is a aggregate column. Just change `count([pass_id])` to `count(distinct [pass_id])` in my query to count number of people. About your question, I would personally use temp table or table variable to store splitted parameter. And work with that table

Comment: I missed the pass_id in group clause. If i get door_code parameter like '000A', '000B', '000C', and edit that string to build up column headers, would that be vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: How are you forming your parameter?

Comment: @door_codes = N'''0021'',''0026'',''0027'',''0028'' This is the actual Parameter i used in procedure. When called from application level a string like " '0021', '0026', '0027', '0028'  ", would be passed, and in the procedure, i split it, and join it to [0021], [0026], [0027], [0028] to use it as column header.

Comment: @ringord, seems to be safe

Comment: uzi, what if i use tvp, how would you turn table 000A, 000B, 000C into column header like [000A], [000B], [000C]?

Comment: @ringord, with `for xml`, `stuff` and `quotename`

Comment: Is there anyway i could do it without using @sql variable, without sp_executesql?